enable avx512 zmm registers in gdb
I'm running mingw64 gdb on windows and I'm trying to debug some c and fortran mixed program that has inline asm. The problem I'm m having is that zmm registers are not available to view. I read thru the docs for gdb and it says features have to be enabled for your architecture. I don't have the slightest idea how except that gdb identifies the cpu as architecture of i386 x86-64.
How do I enable vector registers specifically avx512 zmm registers?
I tried using lldb; same problem.
Compiling gdb manually on windows using msys2 is more than I'm capable of.
Im using an intel i7 1185g7. It supports avx512 and many extensions. The inline asm executes fine. I'm using mingw64 gcc and gfortran to compile.
I've tried in gdb:

info registers all
info registers vec
layout reg
i r $zmm0
i r $zmm0h
i r zmm0
i r zmm0h
i r %zmm0
i r %zmm0h

gdb always returns "invalid register ...".
I think the architecture is right:
(gdb) show architecture

The target architecture is set to "auto" (currently "i386:x86-64").

There is also an option for intel:
(gdb) set architecture i386:x86-64:intel

The target architecture is set to "i386:x86-64:intel".

It doesn't make a difference. I can see the xmm registers fine but not the zmm registers.

I would have expected i r zmm0 or p /x $zmm0.v8_int64 to work.  Or apparently i r $regname works, too for supported registers.  I don't know if it's possible to compile GDB without AVX-512 support in a GDB version new enough to have that at all.

Looks like both ymm and zmm registers are currently not supported on gdb for windows.

so in the gdb im using there are example xml files to enable features in gdb. it looks like core, sse is enabled but not avx or avx512. theres no way of enabling this on windows?

Apparently you have to use a special set of functions to get these register values (see XState Context), and this just isn't implemented in gdb (and lldb). And I could find no ticket requesting this feature.

gcc and lldb aside, there are various debuggers for Windows (as opposed to apparently being half-ported to Windows with features missing) that don't have this issue. WinDbg, the visual studio built-in debugger, x64dbg, lots of extra options that I'm not all going to list
